# PostScript interface for non-PostScript printers with IPP and IIS?

Tags: iis, printing

Is it possible to use IPP and IIS to provide a PostScript interface for a printer that does not natively support PostScript?

The aim here is to provide a generic interface for printing over IPP, so that clients can standardize on a single driver (PostScript) instead of having to download drivers for different printers. I could do this with CUPS, but would like to know if it is feasible with IIS, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason that CUPS isn't an option?

Comment: CUPS is definitely an option. I am investigating whether it is possible to achieve the same results with IIS as well, in order to compare alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript is available for windows.

This indicates that you may be able to make ghostscript appear to be a [local printer](http://blogs.windowsnetworking.com/wnadmin/2006/10/12/howto-create-pdf-in-windows-using-ghostscript-and-redmon/).

Which could then be shared.

But I don't think its worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://pnm2ppa.sourceforge.net/PPA_networking/PPA_networking-4.html) discusses how to set up GhostScript and use it as a printer destination on a Windows machine.  This has a list of various c[ommercial PostScript tools](http://www.inkguides.com/commercial-postscript-software.asp) including PostScript rendering software.